# Fully Bit-Banged SPI

Tags: rpi.gpio, spi

I would like to be able to run SPI over whatever GPIO pins are available on my Pi (2 and Zero mainly). Is there any decent full code example for SPI Read/Write using RPi.GPIO on arbitrary pins? Speed is not really a major concern.

Comment: Why are the examples found by googling not decent for you?

Comment: None of them (that I've found) actually handle different speeds or chip select pins and they generally seem to just flip the bits as fast as possible, which is not going to work for every device.

Comment: Fair enough.  This sort of open ended question may be better suited to the raspberry pi org forum.  This site works better (in my opinion) if you have some code which you are trying to debug of adapt to your own needs.  So for instance if you find some example code and add inter-bit delays and that doesn't work it may be a better question for this site.